# Allow users to name file to be downloaded

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a link that allows the user to download a CSV formatted version of specific sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.

```
var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId() + "&gid=" + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName').getSheetId();
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ssID + "&exportFormat=csv";
```

The issue is that the downloaded CSV file is named "SpreadsheetName - SheetName", which isn't ideal. Is there any way to change that to how the user wants to named the downloaded CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

One method is [`ContentService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content), paired with a webapp function (i.e. `doPost(e)` or `doGet(e)`). The event object will contain [useful information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters), such as your desired output filename and the sheet in question to be output, if you add those to the script url, e.g. `https://script.google.com/......./exec?fileName=somename&sheets=Sheet1,Sheet2....`

An example function:

```
function doGet(eventObject) {
  if(!eventObject) throw new Error("You called this from the script editor.");
  else console.log(eventObject); // View the event object on Stackdriver.

  // Arrays of named URL parameters.
  var params = eventObject.parameters; 
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  // Assumes the url contains a named 'sheets' parameter.
  params.sheets.forEach(function (sheetName) {
    /* your code that gets data from each sheet with the given
       name and converts it into a CSV-formatted string. */
    output.append(thatDataStringYouGot);
  });
    // Assumes the url contains a named "fileName" parameter.
  output.setMimetype(MimeType.CSV).downloadAsFile(eventObject.parameter.fileName);
  return output;
}
```